# Deserializing a PHP serialized string in node js

Tags: php, node.js, regex, mongodb, deserialization

I have a PHP serialized string which I was unserializing using **php-serialize** or `'locutus/php/var/unserialize'` in Node js.

```
"a:2:{s:3:\"$or\";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:\"$and\";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:20:\"attributes.FIRSTNAME\";C:18:\"MongoDB\\BSON\\Regex\":49:{a:2:{s:7:\"pattern\";s:2:\"^a\";s:5:\"flags\";s:1:\"i\";}}}}}}s:4:\"$and\";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:3:\"$or\";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:8:\"batch_id\";a:1:{s:7:\"$exists\";b:1;}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:\"sc\";a:1:{s:3:\"$ne\";i:-2;}}}}}}"
```

I am getting error when I try to unserialize it stating:

```
SyntaxError: Unknown / Unhandled data type(s): c
```

I am unserializing like :

```
unserialize(<serialized_string>);
```

**Update:**

I am trying the below code when using php-serialize library:

```
const PhpSerialize = require("php-serialize");
const serialised_str = 'a:2:{s:3:"$or";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:"$and";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:20:"attributes.FIRSTNAME";C:18:"MongoDB\BSON\Regex":49:{a:2:{s:7:"pattern";s:2:"^a";s:5:"flags";s:1:"i";}}}}}}s:4:"$and";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:3:"$or";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:8:"batch_id";a:1:{s:7:"$exists";b:1;}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:"sc";a:1:{s:3:"$ne";i:-2;}}}}}}';
console.log(PhpSerialize.unserialize(serialised_str));
```

And getting this error:

```
Error: Expected '"' at index 106 while unserializing payload
```

If I try to unserialize the string with no classes, it works. But if the string is having somePHP class, it stops working.

Please someone help me in solving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [BSON Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson)

Comment: @Triby I have tried with BSON package. it didn't work. It gave me error Error: bson size must be >= 5, is 0.

Comment: So, your BSON has errors, what did you to to debug and view its contents?

Comment: Actually it's right. when unserialized in PHP it was showing tha expected result but not in node

Comment: But you need to know what you're getting in node before trying to unserialize.

Comment: yes , actually this BSON has a attributes.FIRSTNAME which will contain a regex i.e all the names that starts with a.

Comment: Please edit your question, add the PHP code where you serialize the data and send it to node.js, also the code where you try to unserialize it on node.js

Comment: You have a serialized class `C:18:\"MongoDB\\BSON\\Regex\"` that is not supported by the unserialize function. Maybe PHP can do it if class is loaded before, but don't know if it works on node.js

Answer (score 1):

```
"a:2:{s:3:\"$or\";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:4:\"$and\";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:20:\"attributes.FIRSTNAME\";C:18:\"MongoDB\\BSON\\Regex\":49:{a:2:{s:7:\"pattern\";s:2:\"^a\";s:5:\"flags\";s:1:\"i\";}}}}}}s:4:\"$and\";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:3:\"$or\";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:8:\"batch_id\";a:1:{s:7:\"$exists\";b:1;}}i:1;a:1:{s:2:\"sc\";a:1:{s:3:\"$ne\";i:-2;}}}}}}"
```

This is not BSON. BSON is binary and you wouldn't be able to read any of it like text. The above looks like it could be PHP-serialized PHP data structure.

It sounds like you should clarify what the different pieces you are working with are (first of all for yourself, since you seem to be confusing the various serialization formats) and then revise your question.

Sometimes when people say the phrase "BSON document" they don't actually mean BSON at all - they simply are referring to a map of keys to values, potentially with certain properties like the keys are all strings.

Comment: you are right. This is PHP serialized string.I confused it with BSON definition. So what happens is this is serialized in PHP and sent to node server where I need to unserialize this.  I have used various libraries for this in node but not getting the answer. Error I am getting is stated in the question.

Comment: So your question is: I send some data in format A to an application, which deserializes it to a native data structure D, potentially transforms it in unspecified ways, then eventually sends it to a library which complains about an issue with format C. You need to narrow down where the problem is. Is the native representation D your application is working with in the middle of this process correct?

Comment: I have edited the question.This is PHP serialised string which I am unserializing in javascript and I am getting error

Comment: There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-serialize. What is "locutus"?

Comment: I have used php-serialize. It is not able to unserialize it due to class in the string.
Locutus is also a library in which other languages’ standard libraries are converted to JavaScript.

Comment: Create a minimum reproducible example using php-serialize, post that example, the input and the result that you get when you run it.

Comment: I have mentioned the input and the result in the main question under "update". Please check.